# Query on nested type with aggregation on nested types returns unexpected results

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

We are using elasticsearch 5.6.4. As mentioned in the ES [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_filtering_queries_and_aggregations.html),

> aggregation operates in the context of the query scope, any filter
>   applied to the query will also apply to the aggregation.

Now, what I have is this : 
An index with mapping :

```
{
    "properties":{
        "asset":{
            "properties":{
                "customerId":{
                    "type":"long"
                }
            }
        },
        "software":{
            "type": "nested",
            "properties":{
                "id":{
                    "type":"long"
                },
                "name":{
                    "type":"text",
                     "fields": {
                        "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword",
                            "ignore_above": 256
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have created several documents to perform various tests here. Docs are indexed on customerId. I have in all 10 documents each having 2 or more softwares. For testing aggregations on softwares, I created softwares with same ID across multiple documents. e.g. I have software with Id as 12 twice in doc with customerId 1 and 2 and 3. Also, Doc with customerId 2 has two softwares with Id as 12.

So there are 4 softwares with Id as 12 across documents 1, 2 and 3.
The aggregation result includes only the documents with customerId 1 and not 2 and 3 ,when this query is run :

```
{
  "query" : {
    "term":{
        "asset.customerId":1
    }
  },
  "aggregations" : {
    "aggs" : {
      "nested" : {
        "path" : "software"
      },
      "aggregations" : {
        "software.id.agg" : {
          "terms" : {
            "field" : "software.id",
            "size" : 10,
            "min_doc_count" : 1,
            "shard_min_doc_count" : 0,
            "show_term_doc_count_error" : false,
            "order" : [
              {
                "_count" : "desc"
              },
              {
                "_term" : "asc"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But when the query filter is run on a nested type (software.id), aggregation result includes all the docs (1, 2 and 3) and hence the buckets which should be filtered out because of the query are also present. :

```
{
  "query" : {
    "nested" : {
            "query" : {
              "match_phrase_prefix" : {
                "software.id" : {
                  "query" : 12,
                  "slop" : 100,
                  "max_expansions" : 50,
                  "boost" : 1.0
                }
              }
            },
            "path" : "software",
            "ignore_unmapped" : false,
            "score_mode" : "none",
            "boost" : 1.0
          }
  },
  "aggregations" : {
    "aggs" : {
      "nested" : {
        "path" : "software"
      },
      "aggregations" : {
        "software.id.agg" : {
          "terms" : {
            "field" : "software.id",
            "size" : 10,
            "min_doc_count" : 1,
            "shard_min_doc_count" : 0,
            "show_term_doc_count_error" : false,
            "order" : [
              {
                "_count" : "desc"
              },
              {
                "_term" : "asc"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

What's the correct way to provide the query filter on nested type so that it is applied on aggregation?

Comment: Maybe you should try [Filter Aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-filter-aggregation.html) and move the logic of the query into there (under Nested Aggregation).

Comment: Hey, that's right, it worked. Sorry for the late response.